# Can not upload my image on Imagebb, the hosting is showing error

Tags: reactjs

Here is the code, I can't upload image on imgbb. Error message showing:  "Empty upload source."
please solve it for me

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
  console.log(data.img);

  const imgAPIKey = 'APIKEY'
  const img = data.img[0]
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('img', img)
  const url = `https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=${imgAPIKey}`
  fetch(url,
      {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData
       })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
          console.log('imgbb', result)
      })
}
```

Comment: You should remove your API key from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally got solution.
Actually imgbb isn't accepting 'img'. They are accepting 'image' only .
so solution is:

```
 const image = data.img[0]

  const formData = new FormData()

  formData.append('image', image)
```